# Insert multiple rows with same primary key in sql using php

Tags: php, mysql

Want to insert multiple records with same primary.
i am try to insert multiple record with same primary key but the sql giving the error "duplicate primary key".
it can possible to insert multiple rows with id or primary key.?

Comment: duplicate primary keys is a non sequitur. primary keys MUST be unique, or they're not primary keys.

Answer (score 4):

Primary Key is intended to be **unique**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html

you can have a **Composite Primary Key**:

```
CREATE TABLE track(
  album CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  dsk INTEGER NOT NULL,
  posn INTEGER NOT NULL,
  song VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (album, dsk, posn)
)
```

Composite unique keys are very useful for when you want to prevent duplicate data across a number of database fields in a table.

http://www.alphadevx.com/a/382-Adding-a-composite-unique-key-to-an-existing-MySQL-table

Answer (score 3):

The whole idea of a primary key is to have a unique identifier for each row, so you can not do that. However, if you want a way of grouping rows, you can either add a group column to your table, or create a table for the grouping. For example group_members and have that contain two columns, "group_id" and "row_id".

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a primary key is it is unique and cannot be duplicated.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp

Answer (score 0):

Primary Keys are supposed to be unique, that's why the MySQL is throwing you that error.

Read more about primary key

[SQL primary key](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp)

Comment: I know that primary key is unique but i want insert multiple rows against same id. how to do that?

Comment: Where do you want to insert them? in a different table? you just want subitems related to that primary id?

Comment: In a same table. yes there are different products and every product has its own quantity and weight. i want to insert all agianst one id.

Comment: You should edit your question and add a ER diagram of your current tables, because you can't duplicate PK on the same table. you should work with Foreign keys and relationships.