# how to insert distinct two column pairs if not exit in the table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two columns.

```
Recommendation
——————————
movieID | String
recMovieID | String
```

I want to insert unique pair to that database. I want to check `INSERT` statement such that it will check if the pair already exist. If the pair is new, the `INSERT` statement is executed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert multiple rows with same primary key in sql using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288038/insert-multiple-rows-with-same-primary-key-in-sql-using-php)

Comment: have the db enforce uniqueness on the composite

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898599/insert-query-check-if-record-exists-if-not-insert-it I think it may be useful to your case.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE Recommendation ADD CONSTRAINT movieRecUnique UNIQUE(movieID,recMovieID)
```